# getting started with libmms

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, streaming, mms

Actually, the title explains it all...
I want to read a stream, but have no idea from where to start.
I've searched the web for some documentation/tutorial/whatever with no luck.

Any help using this lib would be very appreciated.

[CLARIFICATION]
I am talking about MMS stream protocol library that can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/libmms).
LibMMS is a common library for parsing mms:// and mmsh:// type network streams. These are commonly used to stream Windows Media Video content over the web.
[/CLARIFICATION]

Comment: It looks a bit dodgy to me.  There's no documentation on the web site, but I guess you could use the sample code to find out how to use it.  Or you could send e-mail to the project and ask them to write some documentation.  Or the docs for the xine project from which a lot of the code came might shed some light.

Comment: Jeremy, where did you find the sample code? 
I can't seem to put my pointer on it :S

Comment: I don't think "the title explains it all". It doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Jalf, have you tried reading the text below the title? 
I have explained it more extensively later on to avoid any confusion. If you read the text, at the end you'll agree with me... It's all summarized in the title.
I am just asking for help to get started with libMMS.